# Checkout with Braintree payment with 3d secure give error "Please try again with another form of payment."

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, braintree

Preconditions

1. Magento 2.3.X
2. configure Braintree payment with 3d secure for Production Environment

Steps to reproduce

1. List item
2. Add to cart any product
3. Go to checkout
4. select shipping method
5. select Credit Card (Braintree) as the payment method
6. fill details and click Place Order

Expected result:
1. order placed successfully

Actual result:
1. give the error "Please try again with another form of payment".

Comment: think link help you 
https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007753688-How-we-solved-Braintree-Magento-2-checkout-issues-with-our-Magento-2-1-store